# How can I disable autosaving of xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I have installed Xcode 9. Everytime I add some resources like pictures to the left project sources menu I need wait one or some second like a autosaving is running.

Also, when I change some configuration of info-plist of into the target, this is loading or saving and it's slow and desperate.

How can I change this configuration? Thanks!